# Is there a name for the relation of a directed set?

Tags: terminology

If $(X,R)$ is an ordered set then we say $R$ is an order in $X$, how do we call the relation $R$ if $(X,R)$ is a directed set? A direction in X?

Comment: What do you mean by '*directed*' here? It is a special *partial order*, isn't it? Then I would refer to $R$ as the *partial order of the directed set*.

Comment: @Berci No, it is not a special partial order since in a direct set the antisymmetry does not need to hold, so it is not true that every directed set is a poset. A set is directed if it is equipped with a preorder and the aditional property that every pair of elements of the set is bounded above.